# Jade using reserved word as tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am using jade to template XML files and one of my tags is called `<block>...</block>`.

So the snippet of my jade file is as follows:

```
block
    ...
```

When compiling I get the following error: Anonymous blocks are not allowed unless they are part of a mixin.

I assume this is because "block" is a reserved word. So my question is how does one use a reserved word as a tag?

Any information is appreciated.

Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string interpolation on a fixed string:

```
#{'block'}
  foo hello
```

Found [here](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/826#issuecomment-10952373).

Comment: Thank you! Do you perhaps have a reference to the jade docs or does it only exists as a github issue?

Comment: @Paul I haven't found any reference to this construct in the docs. Apparently, it's valid to use string interpolation for tags as well (as opposed to just for content), which is something I didn't know either :-)

Comment: Awesome find! Thank you again.